# Приватный чат в Ratchet

Tags: php, ratchet

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примером или способом, как реализовывать приватный чат. В голове представляю как это должно быть, но кодом изобразить что-то не выходит.

Дано:

1. id отправителя (например, 12334),
2. id получателя (например, 12336),
3. текст сообщения,
4. уникальный идентификатор комнаты (например, UCODE123331)

Все ID'ы пишутся в базу. Стандартная конструкция у либы идет такая

```
                        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
                            if ($from !== $client) {
                                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                                $client->send($msg);
                            }
                        }
```

Но это отправляет сообщение вообще всем, кроме отправителя. Я полагаю, что можно как то проверить, если существует уникальный идентификатор комнаты, то отправлять сообщение пользователю из этой комнаты. В ином случае отправлять всем. Вроде просто, а туплю ужас как. В гугле лазил, но путного не нашел. Выручайте

Comment: поменяйте условие в `if` под свои нужды

Comment: @ArchDemon менял..но полагаю, что менял неправильно. Делал что-то вроде
if ($from !== $client && id_получателя==$client) и это ничего не отправляло. Там ведь каждый раз новый ID ratchet'ом дается при обновлении страницы и хз как по нему ловить нужного юзера

Comment: Ну значит в `$client` находится не id получателя

Comment: @ArchDemon в $client находятся ID'ы, которые присваивает ratchet каждому юзеру. Они не статичны и при обновлении страницы меняются. Как их запоминать тогда ?

Comment: Как хотите, так и запоминайте

Comment: @ArchDemon Удружили, спасибо :(

Comment: Изучайте примеры в [Интернете](https://medium.com/hackeradda/real-time-one-to-one-time-chat-application-using-ratchet-php-websockets-80cbf9e5b7b4), благо вы не первый кто изобретает велосипед приватного чата с Ratchet.

Comment: У вас получилось решить эту проблему? Я сейчас столкнулся с подобной

Comment: @Vanya228 Да..абы как, но работает

Comment: @sousage1212 можете исходники класса показать?